# Meteor + webpack tutorial with blaze instead of react?

Tags: meteor, reactjs, webpack, meteor-blaze

My project is getting too big for the meteor build system (>1min load time) and I therefore want to switch to webpack. 
All the tutorials and boilerplates that I could find use a combination of Meteor/react/webpack, but my project uses blaze and I currently do not want to switch to react.

It is hard for me to figure out what code bits in the sample projects belong to react and which are necessary to make webpack work. (I am not really familiar with react).

Does anybody know a tutorial or sample github project using webpack with blaze?

Comment: According to [the current version of the meteor-webpack readme](https://github.com/thereactivestack/meteor-webpack/tree/master/packages/webpack/#framework), it is still in development. However, [on his blog Benoit recommends](https://forums.meteor.com/t/webpack-compiler-inside-meteor-es6-modules-hot-reload-and-code-splitting/11264/109) taking a look at [this project](https://github.com/AdamBrodzinski/meteor-webpack-react/tree/blaze-example) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

For all those still landing on this page in 2019 - Meteor 1.8 has improved build times up to a few seconds even on larger codebases and 1.8.1 has done this also for windows. Please update if you are still running older versions. This should therefore be not of a common issue anymore.